# importing a list of lists

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I have a list of lists, a list of file paths for some number of directories.

I want to import that files as lists of lists, where instead of getting one massive 1D list, **the distinct directories are preserved from which the imported data goes into.**

```
filePaths={{"/dir1/a.txt", "/dir1/b.txt", "/dir1/c.txt"},  {"/dir2/d.txt", 
  "/dir2/e.txt", "/dir2/f.txt"}}

Import[#,"Table"]& @/filePaths[[a]]&/@Range[Length[filePaths]]
```

I tried using a double mapping method, but mathematica gets upset when I try to do it, even though trying Print[] as follows gives me the expected file paths

```
Print[#] & /@ filePaths[[a]] & /@ Range[Length[filePaths]]
```

Comment: How are you using `a` if is not defined? To clarify your question, you basically want `n` lists with `m` files within, where `n` is your number of directories? (what do you mean by 'directories are preserved'?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get n lists of m files (by preservation I mean that all the files associated with a given dir are in the list). this would define a but doesn't resolve it `Print[#] & /@ filePaths[[a]] & /@ 
 Table[a, {a, 1, Length[filePaths]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the data into a list with `n` elements, each element having in itself `m` tables imported.

For instance, assuming every dataset you care about is in a separate `.txt` file within each of the directories, you can do:

`directories={"C:\\dir1", "C:\\dir2"}` (list your directories of interest)

```
myData = Table[Import[#, "Table"] & /@ 
  FileNames["*.txt", directories[[a]]], {a, 1, Length[directories]}];
```

This makes a list of length `n`, containing the data of every `.txt` file found in every one of the directories in `directories`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that I list the directories, not the full path files (the full path file is detected with `FileNames`, which searches for files ending in "*.txt" -the asterisk is to mean that the file name can be anything, only the termination .txt matters-)

Comment: I was able to modify the wildcard :-) thank you!!!